# Capybara / Rspec Controller testing with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test my controllers using Capybara. I have tried numerous ways, but for some reason I can not get it to see the current_user session.  I know the login works when I run my spec for it. I'm also visiting the login page before my controller test. But it always seems to redirect me back when the :logged_in function is hit.

So not sure what I'm missing?

Here's what I have..

session_controller

```
    def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if( user && user.authenticate(params[:password]))
        user.update_attribute(:token, User.token_digest)
        flash[:notice] = "Success"
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        session[:token] = user.token
        redirect_to dashboard_index_path  
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Failed"
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid user name or password"
        render "new"
    end
end
```

application_controller

```
protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :logged_in 
private  

      def current_user 
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
      end
      helper_method :current_user

      def logged_in
        if !current_user
            redirect_to root_url
          return
        end
        if session[:token] != current_user.token
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      end
```

products_controller_spec

```
it 'Should display new product form' do
    user_login
    visit new_product_path
    response.body.should have_content("<h1>Create New Product</h1>")
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
def user_login
  visit root_path #this is new_session
  fill_in "username", :with => "admin"
  fill_in "password", :with => "111111"
  click_button "Login"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I got it working,Not sure its politically correct way but.. instead of visiting the page, I'm just hard setting the session.  In spec_helper.rb..

```
def user_login
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    session[:token] = User.token_digest
end
```